# Where can I train my Pokemon for the Elite Four?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I really want to train my Pokemon to a certain level before I get to the Elite Four, so can anyone suggest some good places to train?

Here's my team:

[image: screenshot of my team]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good places:

> - **Battle Chateau**. You may even run into some Gym Leaders after becoming Marquis(male) or Machioness(female) rank. Or trainers with a whole team of *Audino*, which gives a huge chunk of EXP points.
> - **Restaurants in Lumiose City**. It is recommended that you choose either a Triple Battle or a Rotation Battle. If you choose Double Battle, you'll only fight two Pokemon per trainer instead of 3, and you'll miss out on fighting Pokemon like a lvl 63 *Audino*.

Beside that, there are a few techniques you can use to boost the incoming experience points.

> - Give your Pokemon the **Lucky Egg**. The *Lucky Egg* is a held item that will increase the experience points given to the Pokemon at the end of battle. This item can be found in the *Coumarine City Hotel* and occasionally held by *Chansey* (Friend Safari).
> - Increase your Pokemon's affection in **Pokemon-Amie**. Another way to get extra experience points from any Pokemon in your game is to increase the Pokemon's affection in *Pokemon-Amie*. Play games with it, pet it, and feed it until the hearts are filled up. You can check a Pokemon's *Pokemon-Amie* stats when you try to switch to another Pokemon at the *Pokemon-Amie* menu.
> - Use the **Exp. Point Power**. If you use this *O-Power*, Pokemon will obtain even more experience points after battles, but only for three minutes after using the *O-Power*. This *O-Power* can be obtained in the *Anistar City Pokemon Center*.

Source [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-x-y/How_to_Quickly_Level_Up_Pokemon).